# ASP.NET MVC 5 and Interface implementation problem

Tags: vb.net, interface

Trying to implement an interface like this but unable to do so. I can't remove `Shared` keyword from `GetMenu()` call which will make this function inaccessible to all existing calls. Am I missing something basic or it requires dependency injection?

```
Public Interface IMenu
    Function ReadMenu(Path As String) 
    Function SaveMenu()
End Interface
      
Public Class MenuCol
    Implements IMenu

     Public Shared Function GetMenu(ByVal Id As Integer)
         ReadMenu(Path) 
      ' -- Error here  - cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared or Shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class
     End Function

     Public Function ReadMenu(Path As String) As Object Implements IMenu.ReadMenu
        'Logic for Read
     End Function

     Public Function SaveMenu() As Object Implements IMenu.SaveMenu
        'Logic for Save
     End Function
    
End Class
```

Comment: The [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) give you a decent overview.  The error message really tells you everything though.  Shared methods don't have a instance of the type, you would have to create one in the GetMenu method, then call ReadMenu on that instance.  Also make next to no sense to have a function without a return type

Comment: This really comes down to what the `Shared` keyword means. You should do some research and learn that. It's not just a magic solution that allows you to access members where you otherwise couldn't. Either you want a `Shared` method or you want an instance method. You need to decide and then implement it appropriately. We can't tell you which it should be based on the information you have provided.